# Freeswitch. Error 487 Role Conflict (on REINVITE)

Tags: webrtc, sip, freeswitch, sdp, ice

I'm trying to add video track to stream and then call `renegotiate()` from JsSip. However, when I'm doing it from caller it works fine, but when I'm doing it from callee it's not working (session terminating).
I looked into the Freeswitch logs and found next lines:

```
2017-05-25 07:41:02.177674 [NOTICE] switch_rtp.c:4591 Activating RTP video ICE: 1Xn5:7JJhZkbbu6MxTEpr 95.29.39.101:55140
2017-05-25 07:41:02.177674 [INFO] switch_core_media.c:3675 Activating video RTCP PORT 55140
2017-05-25 07:41:02.177674 [INFO] switch_core_media.c:3684 Skipping video RTCP ICE (Same as RTP)
2017-05-25 07:41:02.177674 [INFO] switch_core_media.c:6717 RE-SETTING video DTLS
2017-05-25 07:41:02.177674 [INFO] switch_rtp.c:3574 Activate RTP/RTCP video DTLS client
2017-05-25 07:41:02.177674 [INFO] switch_rtp.c:3723 Changing video DTLS state from OFF to HANDSHAKE
2017-05-25 07:41:02.187678 [WARNING] switch_rtp.c:970 sofia/internal/nn9s29br@2cjo9eh03237.invalid got audio stun binding response 487 Role Conflict
2017-05-25 07:41:02.187678 [WARNING] switch_rtp.c:982 audio STUN Changing role to CONTROLLED
2017-05-25 07:41:02.237684 [WARNING] switch_rtp.c:970 sofia/internal/nn9s29br@2cjo9eh03237.invalid got audio stun binding response 487 Role Conflict
2017-05-25 07:41:02.237684 [WARNING] switch_rtp.c:979 audio STUN Changing role to CONTROLLING
2017-05-25 07:41:02.257682 [NOTICE] sofia.c:1012 Hangup sofia/internal/nn9s29br@2cjo9eh03237.invalid [CS_EXCHANGE_MEDIA] [NORMAL_CLEARING]
2017-05-25 07:41:02.297671 [NOTICE] switch_ivr_bridge.c:1751 Hangup sofia/internal/1001@default [CS_EXECUTE] [NORMAL_CLEARING]
2017-05-25 07:41:02.297671 [NOTICE] switch_core_session.c:1682 Session 2 (sofia/internal/nn9s29br@2cjo9eh03237.invalid) Ended
2017-05-25 07:41:02.297671 [NOTICE] switch_core_session.c:1686 Close Channel sofia/internal/nn9s29br@2cjo9eh03237.invalid [CS_DESTROY]
2017-05-25 07:41:02.307657 [NOTICE] switch_core_session.c:1682 Session 1 (sofia/internal/1001@default) Ended
2017-05-25 07:41:02.307657 [NOTICE] switch_core_session.c:1686 Close Channel sofia/internal/1001@default [CS_DESTROY]
2017-05-25 07:46:09.617693 [NOTICE] switch_channel.c:1104 New Channel sofia/internal/trunk@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx [804db9ee-6307-42fe-ad82-4d0d7684e6d2]
```

Maybe there is some config issues...

**UPDATE**

Reinvite offer SDP below:

```
type: offer, sdp: v=0
o=- 5417896742972440455 3 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE audio video
a=msid-semantic: WMS NEWUOS8D1IPpEVh9SKJSeHBtDJGuxHN0Km4Q
m=audio 58796 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 102 9 0 8 103 101 127 104 106 105 13         112 113
c=IN IP4 93.81.4.243
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=candidate:2131708102 1 udp 2113937151 192.168.0.100 58796 typ host generation 0 network-cost 50
a=candidate:842163049 1 udp 1677729535 93.81.4.243 58796 typ srflx raddr 192.168.0.100 rport 58796 generation 0 network-cost 50
a=ice-ufrag:eXlC
a=ice-pwd:AyYvLjMPpRjD9MAFCKBB3j4e
a=fingerprint:sha-256 BE:B5:DF:63:F6:DC:D4:35:5A:E1:D0:02:18:AF:C7:4F:FD:70:CC:11:50:92:45:E8:0F:B6:09:72:52:5B:C4:DB
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:audio
a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
a=sendrecv
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:102 opus/48000/2
a=fmtp:102 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:103 telephone-event/48000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=rtpmap:127 ISAC/16000
a=rtpmap:104 ISAC/32000
a=rtpmap:106 CN/32000
a=rtpmap:105 CN/16000
a=rtpmap:13 CN/8000
a=rtpmap:112 telephone-event/32000
a=rtpmap:113 telephone-event/16000
a=ssrc:1711904775 cname:hP+1FLed7h34pNAH
a=ssrc:1711904775 msid:NEWUOS8D1IPpEVh9SKJSeHBtDJGuxHN0Km4Q 3f7852cd-9068-4392-a734-c94d1c631818
a=ssrc:1711904775 mslabel:NEWUOS8D1IPpEVh9SKJSeHBtDJGuxHN0Km4Q
a=ssrc:1711904775 label:3f7852cd-9068-4392-a734-c94d1c631818
m=video 51998 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 98 100 126 125 97 99 124 123
c=IN IP4 93.81.4.243
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=candidate:2131708102 1 udp 2113937151 192.168.0.100 51998 typ host generation 0 network-cost 50
a=candidate:842163049 1 udp 1677729535 93.81.4.243 51998 typ srflx raddr 192.168.0.100 rport 51998 generation 0 network-cost 50
a=ice-ufrag:eXlC
a=ice-pwd:AyYvLjMPpRjD9MAFCKBB3j4e
a=fingerprint:sha-256 BE:B5:DF:63:F6:DC:D4:35:5A:E1:D0:02:18:AF:C7:4F:FD:70:CC:11:50:92:45:E8:0F:B6:09:72:52:5B:C4:DB
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:video
a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=extmap:4 urn:3gpp:video-orientation
a=extmap:5 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
a=extmap:6 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay
a=recvonly
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp-rsize
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=rtpmap:98 VP9/90000
a=rtcp-fb:98 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:98 nack
a=rtcp-fb:98 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:98 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:98 transport-cc
a=rtpmap:100 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:100 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:100 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:100 transport-cc
a=fmtp:100 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42e01f
a=rtpmap:126 red/90000
a=rtpmap:125 ulpfec/90000
a=rtpmap:97 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:97 apt=96
a=rtpmap:99 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:99 apt=98
a=rtpmap:124 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:124 apt=100
a=rtpmap:123 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:123 apt=126
```

Reinvite answer SDP:

```
type: answer, sdp: v=0
o=FreeSWITCH 1495981785 1495981786 IN IP4 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
s=FreeSWITCH
c=IN IP4 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
t=0 0
a=msid-semantic: WMS IoFoWVXMBVpdoXbZZ1FM0X9KjiJsXLhw
m=audio 17400 RTP/SAVPF 102 9 0 8 103 101
a=rtpmap:102 opus/48000/2
a=fmtp:102 useinbandfec=1; maxaveragebitrate=30000;         maxplaybackrate=48000; ptime=20; minptime=10; maxptime=40; stereo=1
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:103 telephone-event/48000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=fingerprint:sha-256 D2:20:E1:7A:E0:0B:63:34:03:A3:2D:77:E7:7D:AF:F8:9C:47:D4:22:21:7C:74:C2:14:D1:27:5F:C2:0F:EF:B8
a=setup:passive
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp:17400 IN IP4 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
a=ssrc:87870097 cname:0NKMyypZjE2ys3oh
a=ssrc:87870097 msid:IoFoWVXMBVpdoXbZZ1FM0X9KjiJsXLhw a0
a=ssrc:87870097 mslabel:IoFoWVXMBVpdoXbZZ1FM0X9KjiJsXLhw
a=ssrc:87870097 label:IoFoWVXMBVpdoXbZZ1FM0X9KjiJsXLhwa0
a=ice-ufrag:VTULHUmQ2V8Pxfbn
a=ice-pwd:SL0haf6kKZI3SWbEGVfdFrTx
a=candidate:6665814401 1 udp 659136 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 17400 typ host generation     0
a=candidate:6665814401 2 udp 659136 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 17400 typ host generation 0
a=ptime:20
m=video 17728 RTP/SAVPF 96
b=AS:1024
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=fingerprint:sha-256 D2:20:E1:7A:E0:0B:63:34:03:A3:2D:77:E7:7D:AF:F8:9C:47:D4:22:21:7C:74:C2:14:D1:27:5F:C2:0F:EF:B8
a=setup:passive
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp:17728 IN IP4 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm tmmbr
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=ssrc:3634858696 cname:0NKMyypZjE2ys3oh
a=ssrc:3634858696 msid:IoFoWVXMBVpdoXbZZ1FM0X9KjiJsXLhw v0
a=ssrc:3634858696 mslabel:IoFoWVXMBVpdoXbZZ1FM0X9KjiJsXLhw
a=ssrc:3634858696 label:IoFoWVXMBVpdoXbZZ1FM0X9KjiJsXLhwv0
a=ice-ufrag:o27C1oHNw8FNmf8s
a=ice-pwd:JFs75HK4WB90HqLVjIoaXVNk
a=candidate:7203188173 1 udp 659136 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 17728 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:7203188173 2 udp 659135 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 17728 typ host generation 0
a=end-of-candidates
```

**UPDATE 2**

It seems working with this FS branch: FS-10089-combining-inherit_codec-and-ice. I've tested it with JsSip and 'UPDATE' method to renegotiate SDP.